# Android System Installer App "Application Not Installed" why? where is log for this?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am trying to install an unsigned apk by placing in download directory.
Installer comes up and has a few warning like allow to modify properties etc.
I click on install and it just says Application Not Installed?

What is the possible reason for it and in what log file would the installer tell me the problem.
Where is this log file?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be possible that the same application was already installed over to the device but with different computer and now you are trying to install the same unsigned app from your computer.

SOLUTION 1 : uninstall that installed application.
SOLUTION 2 : Sign the application and try to install

This actually happens with the unsigned apk file because for the unsigned apks, android uses the debug.keystore which is different from computer to computer.

Comment: Thanks.  Signing the application works.  However do you know how I can get the tablet to accept an Unsigned App which is faster to generate.  Thanks

Comment: Let me post that as another question just a second.

Comment: Ok. Please answer this if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347804/how-to-get-system-installer-on-tablet-to-accept-unsigned-app

Comment: In my case the installed app is not signed and the app which i am trying to install is signed still i am getting the same error. Are both the file should have to signed or there is any issue in signing so that i am getting that error.

Comment: Well answered, I was searching cause of my problem, eventually found it

Answer (score 4):

`adb logcat` from the official [Android dev tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is likely to be helpful.  (There are some almost useful error dialogs finally in 2.3, but you pretty much need to be a ROM-head or rich enough to throw away phones every couple months to get them.)

Comment: I have not been able to reach device via ADB like I can on my android phone.

Comment: please answer this if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347804/how-to-get-system-installer-on-tablet-to-accept-unsigned-app

Comment: btw do you know what log file i might check where system installer might explain itself better?

Comment: I saw it go by (not that it wasn't obviously coming), but don't have an answer.  It sounds like a lot of the new Android tablets are deliberately crippled.

Comment: I'm still getting used to poking at Android guts; no real idea where any of the log files are yet.  At some point I want to go on a spelunking expedition in `/system` and `/data` and see what goodies are hiding where.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just happened to me : developping from 2 different computers, and here is what the logcat says :`[2011-03-17 23:05:58 - CustomTabs] Uploading CustomTabs.apk onto device 'HT93SKF05669'
[2011-03-17 23:05:59 - CustomTabs] Installing CustomTabs.apk...
[2011-03-17 23:06:06 - CustomTabs] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-03-17 23:06:06 - CustomTabs] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-03-17 23:06:06 - CustomTabs] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.fy.box.android' in a shell.
[2011-03-17 23:06:06 - CustomTabs] Launch canceled!
[2011-03-17 23:08:14 - CustomTabs] ------------------------------
[2011-03-17 23:08:14 - CustomTabs] Android Launch!
[2011-03-17 23:08:14 - CustomTabs] adb is running normally.
[2011-03-17 23:08:14 - CustomTabs] Performing com.fy.box.android.CustomTabActivity activity launch
[2011-03-17 23:08:16 - CustomTabs] Uploading CustomTabs.apk onto device 'HT93SKF05669'
[2011-03-17 23:08:16 - CustomTabs] Installing CustomTabs.apk...
[2011-03-17 23:08:44 - CustomTabs] Success!
[2011-03-17 23:08:44 - CustomTabs] Starting activity com.fy.box.android.CustomTabActivity on device HT93SKF05669`

if you already installed the app, uninstall it, and try to reinstall ... hope this helps !

Comment: thanks. Problem is in my case it did not accept unsigned app.  Please answer this if you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347804/how-to-get-system-installer-on-tablet-to-accept-unsigned-app

Answer (score 0):

for people coming here after multi-user support was introduced to android, thats most probably the cause.

at least in my case.

after installing an app via android studio/adb this app will be installed for every user, including guest

so when you then try to install the same app from an apk on your device, it wont work since its already installed (even after uninstalling it from your main user)

so my solution was:

- go to every user (including guest)
- uninstall app there
- can now install the new one