# How to get System Installer on Tablet to accept Unsigned App

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am in dev mode and have no ADB access to android 2.1 tablet.  I want to just transfer quickly unsigned app to downloads and install.  However installer always says Application not installed without giving reason. So I need to know how to get installer to accept an unsigned app. signed app installs fine, and I do have Unknown Sources Checked under applications.

Answer (score 1):

Go to following

Settings -> Application Settings -> check Unknown Sources.

To install the apk from command prompt you need to follow following command
adb install [file].apk

as per my experience, you installing an unsigned apk from this command is not possible and the only way to install unsigned apk is from running the application from eclipse by right clicking the project and select run and than run an android application.

Comment: So you also have not been able to get these to install except via eclipse?

Comment: as per my experience, installing an unsigned apk from this command is not possible and the only way to install unsigned apk is from running the application from eclipse by right clicking the project and select run and than run an android application.

Comment: Right now eclipse does not see my device tablets. I have not gotten it to recognize the tablet like it can see my phone.

Comment: ok follow this 
Settings -> Application Settings -> Development -> check all 3 options